# If/Else Loop and Auto Email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to coding and trying to jump right in!

I have a new list of customers I'm responsible for in a spreadsheet, and I receive an email from someone I don't immediately recognize.

I need to set up a script to:
1. determine if they are in my book of business
2. if they are in my book of business, send a template email regarding next steps (email A)
3. if they are not in my book of business, send a template email that i'm not their POC and redirecting them to relevant resources (email B)

I believe I need to set up a loop (if/else?) to see if the email I received is from a sender on the list, if it is, send email a, if it isn't send email b.

Does anyone have feedback on my stab below? I've set up a dumbie example I will constantly be working on and updating. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HcLluPhRgl0ihQT0GA-ZFj1KsOPHxl0dU08EFlh2Gss/edit#gid=0

For the if/else I believe I would start with

```
if (CustomerName) {exists Send email A

} else {Send Email B

}

// The code below will send an email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
GmailApp.sendEmail("jlennon@gmail.com", "current time", "The time is: " +     now.toString());
```

Comment: You should get yourself familiar with basic concepts of JavaScript language before going any further. W3Schools is a good place to start. After you get the basics down, check out the following sections of GAS documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/ https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Comment: learn to crawl before you run ; )